# SVG animation on hover clips my text during the transition of opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, velocity.js

I'm using Velocity to animate the opacity of elements in an svg when it is hovered. I've put the text in a foreignobject. When you hover and the text appears and moves, there is always a moment where the text is clipped on it's right end during the transition. Is anyone able to help me fix this to be a smoother animation?

Here's how I've setup the foreign object.

```
    <foreignObject class="diam-foreign" x="60" y="60" width="300" height="297">
      <p class="folio-item-foreign">Make Ready<br />A new project from the Alpine Review and friends</p>
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
```

Here's the code to animate it…

```
$(this).find(".diam-foreign").velocity({ opacity: "1.0", y: "60"}, { delay: 0 });
```

Example here…

http://jsfiddle.net/Rssll/bggLhvyk/2/

Thank you.